# Ignoring DST (Daylight Saving Time) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dst

I am trying to convert a String to a Datetime object without it modifying it and adding an extra hour/offset to the Datetime object.

**This is the code:**

```
string dateStr = "2011-03-18T12:07:00.000+10:00"; //Convert this string to datetime AS IS

DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateStr);

Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + dateStr);
Console.WriteLine("date toString:   " + date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK"));
```

**The output:**

```
Original string: 2011-03-18T12:07:00.000+10:00
date toString:   2011-03-18T13:07:00.000+11:00
```

If anyone can point how I can ignore DST or simply even convert the date back to what I want as a Datetime object, that would be much appreciated.

**Going down the path of modifying the datetime:**
I have tried to convert the Datetime back but I cannot work out how to change the timezone in the Datetime object and when I use a DatetimeOffset object to do this work, when I call the *DatetimeOffset.Datetime* it returns the Datetime without the offset

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: This is in .NET 3.5. 
Is there a URL to Jon Skeet's Noda Time?

Comment: @Eiji, http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Answer (score 3):

A `DateTime` object doesn't contain a time zone.  It only contains a `Kind`, which can be `Utc`, `Local`, or `Unspecified`.

When calling `Convert.ToDateTime`, if *any* offset is present, that offset will be applied and then the value will be converted to the *local* time zone.  That is - the time zone where the code is running.

Then, by using `K` in the output format, it returns the offset of the local time zone for that particular date.

To handle this scenario correctly, use the `DateTimeOffset` type:

```
string dateStr = "2011-03-18T12:07:00.000+10:00";

DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateStr);

Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + dateStr);
Console.WriteLine("dto toString:    " + dto.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK"));
```

Regarding your statement:

> when I call the DatetimeOffset.Datetime it returns the Datetime without the offset

That is correct.  Only the `DateTimeOffset` type has an offset to return.  The `DateTime` object can only return the *local* offset of the machine, or zero for a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Answer (score 0):

TimezoneInfo class in .NET framework can provide the answer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

```
string dateStr = "2011-03-18T12:07:00.000+10:00"; //Convert this string to datetime AS IS

DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date); 

DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
string estKey = "Eastern Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo estTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(estKey);
DateTime estDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, estTimeZone);

Console.WriteLine("Original string: " + dateStr);
Console.WriteLine("date toString:   " + estDateTime);
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but unfortunately we lose the offset in **estDatetime** with that method.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() + TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;

Comment: This correctly applies the given time zone while *ignoring* DST, as was originally asked for.